# Upload base64 encoding Image to WCF service from android

Tags: android, wcf, base64

I have an Android program that can upload an image to a WCF service. The WCF service accepts a JSON object with image name, folder name and a base64 encoding of the image.

I use fiddler for testing that service, I encoded the image from an online service and put it in object. Then composed a POST request ; and then WCF service successfully uploaded image.

But when I use Android HTTP client and doing same thing WCF accepts the request, but I don't recognize the image.

Here is my Android code:

```
try {
    HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(this.remoteBasePath);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put(FILE_NAME, fileName);
    obj.put(FILE_STREAM,fileStream);
    obj.put(FOLDER_NAME, remoteFolder);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString()));
    httpPost.setHeader(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    if(httpResponse!=null){
        TLLog.d(TAG,"StatusCode : "+ httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {                               
            InputStream instream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(instream));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
            instream.close();
            String result = total.toString();
            TLLog.d(TAG,"Image posting result : "+ result);
            return true;
        }
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    TLLog.e(TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    TLLog.e(TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can't understand problem.

Comment: If the problem is just with the image, I guess that `fileStream` is already wrong when you put it into the JSON object.

Comment: thank for your reply.now I'm working on that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys finally i figured out problem.
Problem is encoding so I use class [Base64.java](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) that I downloaded from internet. I use following method for encording

```
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outputStream);
    byte[] bs = outputStream.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded=Base64.encodeBytes(bs);
    return imageEncoded;
}
```

and use returned value as file stream. So my problem is solved.